# Screenshot on failure with Java + Cucumber

Tags: java, cucumber, screenshot

I've found what looks to be a widely-used method to capture screenshots on failure when using Java + Cucumber, which is nice and easy:

```
@After
public void embedScreenshot(Scenario scenario) throws Exception {
    if (scenario.isFailed()) {
        try {
            byte[] screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
            String testName = scenario.getName();
            scenario.embed(screenshot, "image/png");
            scenario.write(testName);
        } catch (WebDriverException wde) {
            System.err.println(wde.getMessage());
        } catch (ClassCastException cce) {
            cce.printStackTrace();}
        }
    }
}
```

How would I write the image file to a folder on the desktop, for example, instead of the project directory by default, and give it a custom name such as the name of my Cucumber test scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the scenario name from the `Scenario scenario` like this:

```
scenario.getName()
```

Then you can just create two `File` objects, one for the screenshot and one of the the destination and use the `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils` to copy the screenshot file to destination folder:

```
FileUtils.copyFile(file, destFile);
```

Comment: Thanks.  I modified the OutputType to be 'FILE' instead of Bytes and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

@gppanter embed method will accept only bytes as args.Then how did you changed that. I was trying to get screenshot for my code

```
@After
public void embedScreenshotOnFail(Scenario s) {
    if (s.isFailed()) try {
        File  screenshot = 
          ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
     s.embed(screenshot , "image/png");
    } catch (ClassCastException cce) {
        cce.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Rakhi.  I have edited my original post to show the code I currently use, which works for me.  (I just learned that SOF doesn't allow code in replies to comments).  I did indeed go back to using 'OutputType.BYTES'.